Sci-fi book about a pebble with a telepathic message, might've been called / had a phrase "Fortress of the mind"
Please help me identify this sci-fi book.
The book is about the main character finding a pebble that contains a secret power and many factions in the galaxy are after it.
The Church is a central power and it performs miracles that seem to be related to telepathic technology. It ends with the discovery of Earth and the pebble is a message from Earth about how after humanity expanded to the stars, Earth took a backseat and developed telepathy. Using telepathy they helped maintain peace but after it was discovered, the rest of the galaxy scoured Earth and telepathy was lost. The church was a sanctuary for telepathic technology to be released to the galaxy again once people were ready to accept it.
The main character becomes the pope and helps to nurture a new generation of telepaths.
I read this book in 2001 but I think the book itself was from the 70s or 80s. It was a classic pulp sci-fi cover.

Also posted to https://www.reddit.com/r/printSF/comments/1g9kwaw/please_help_me_find_this_novel_it_doesnt_seem_to/ (where they recommended posting here) just in case the answer comes up there.

You can accept a correct answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Wrong answers are a good opportunity to [edit] newly realized details in, e.g. "I know that it can't be Mine Mind is a Veritable Fortress because there were no Martian popes and the pebble in question was highly radioactive."

You need to merge your two accounts to accept the correct answer.

A suggested answer was posted to the Reddit post, which seems like a good match, This Fortress World by James Gunn
 

SFWA Grand Master James Gunn's This Fortress World takes place in the far future of our galaxy, when countless civilizations have risen and fallen, leaving only their marvelous scientific achievements as legacy to those worlds which have now fallen into a new Dark Age. On the planet Brancusi, William Dane, an acolyte monk in the all-powerful Church, comes into possession of a crystal pebble dropped in the offering plate, a stolen treasure believed to hold untold secrets of mankind's past. There are powerful men who will stop at nothing, including murder, to recover this ancient artifact. Ignorant of the outside world, who can Dane find to help, and who should be trusted with the pebble's secrets?

The ISFDB entry indicates that it was first published in 1955, with releases in 1977 and 1979 which fits the posted time frame. The Goodreads summary for the 1979 paperback edition mentions Earth.

The universe was ruined...
The Church was the only link between a thousand nameless, warring, fortress worlds. Dane was an acolyte, a Keeper of Mysteries, until he was entrusted with the greatest Mystery of all. It was a stone that spoke. It gleamed in his hand and spoke in his mind with a tiny voice from the far end of Time: "I am Earth..." Then Dane became a warrior for a world he'd never seen!


Yes this is it !!! Thank you so much. Not sure why I cant seem to accept the answer with the original username Vulkan but this is the correct answer . Could a mod please mark it as correct if possible?
